# Best way to call functions while iterating through a foreach loop in Laravel Blade Template

Tags: laravel, function, laravel-blade

I apologize if this is a stupid question – but I haven't found any great answers from searching online.

I have a database table of test scores, that looks something like this:

```
user    | q1 | q2 |  q3  |  q4 | q5
-----------------------------------
user1     3     3     2     1     5
user2     4     2     1     4     5
user1     4     3     3     2     5
```

Any given user can have multiple entries in the table.

In my blade file, I am iterating through all of the rows in the table:

```
@foreach($scores as $score)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$score->user}}</td>
        <td>{{$score->q1}}</td>
        <td>{{$score->q2}}</td>
        <td>{{$score->q3}}</td>
        <td>{{$score->q4}}</td>
        <td>{{$score->q5}}</td>
        <td>{{$score->getTotalScore()}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

It is the function "getTotalScore()" in the last table cell that is causing the problems. I want to perform a slightly complex calculation based on all of the scores of the table – but I prefer not to do it inside the blade file.

I DO have a working version where I make use of @php / @endphp inside the blade file, and do the calculations that way – but it tends to go against my aim to have as little "calculating" in my view as possible.

Trying to put a function in the Model doesn't work, because I am not really returning a relationship. So really, I'm just not sure how to call a function, while in the middle of a @foreach() loop, iterating through returned results.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Comment: What is the type of `$score`? Is it a model?

Comment: The score is just an average of the other 5 scores... but there are a series of conditional statements needed in order to get that average.

So no, I don't have it set up as a model.

But basically, I first need to check that each of those numbers isn't 0... and then I need to average only the numbers that are above 0. Basically, it's just more work than I want to do inside of the blade file – and I would prefer to move the calculation elsewhere.

Comment: You should do all calculations in the controller, not in the blade.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `+=` in order to sum?

Comment: Well... the calculation is more complex than just adding the numbers together. Sorry if my example was misleading. I have a series of conditional statements, and caveats that need taken into consideration before just adding the results together, which is why I want to do it in a function outside of the blade file, versus doing it inline.

Comment: ah i see, so you can use queries in your controller in case you wanted to count some array